# ORACLE SQL: correlated update issue

Tags: oracle, sql-update, correlated

hi guys i have this kind of problem concerning correlated update on oracle.

consider i have a table **params**.

```
id_s    id_p    value    desc
-----------------------------------------------
10064     9      aaa     r
10064     8      bbb     t
10064     4      ccc     t
10064     4      ttt     y
11119     9      ddd     f
11119     8      eee     g 
11119     4      fff     b
11119     4      kkk     x
```

so i want to update **params** to get the following

```
id_s    id_p    value    desc
-----------------------------------------------
10064     9      aaa     r
10064     8      bbb     t
10064     4      ccc     t
10064     4      ttt     y
11119     9      aaa     r
11119     8      bbb     t 
11119     4      ccc     t
11119     4      ttt     y
```

i write update like this

```
update params p1
   set (p1.value, p1.desc) = (
           select p2.value
                , p2.desc 
             from params p2
            where p2.id_s = 10064
              and p2.id_p = p1.id_p
       )
 where p1.id_s = 11119
     ;
```

execution returns error 'ORA01427:Single-row subquery return more than one row'

how can i make this update work?

Comment: your query should be fine - have you run the subquery with `p1.id_p` replaced by some of its values?

Comment: @collapsar yes, i tried. With only one value instead of p1.id_p the update works, but when there are more than one value for p1.id_p then the error 'ORA01427:Single-row subquery return more than one row' returns.

Comment: how do you determine which master and slave records match given your express conditions? eg. for `id_p` = 4 you have 2! = 2 options of correlating the records where `id_s` = 10064 with those where `id_s` = 11119. note that if the choice of correlation doesn't matter you must make sure that the cardinality of source and target set is the same. also note that this kind of invariance is usually a sign of a broken data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add an additional condition to your subquery:

```
update params p1
    set (p1.value, p1.desc) = (
            select p2.value
                 , p2.desc 
              from params p2
             where p2.id_s = 10064
               and p2.id_p = p1.id_p
               and p1.id_s = 11119
        )
  where p1.id_s = 11119
      ;
```

**edit:**
matters are further complicated by the update of the op's spec, which effectively amounts to a partial pk update (as far as the table excerpts given are complete wrt their columns).

a possible solution implements the following basic idea: the result set for the master combination of `id_p`, `id_s` is paired with the result set of for the slave combination of the same columns according to the rank in 2 orderings. the orderings are simply the orderings of the result set according to the columns `value`and `desc`, but of course any other would do as well (note that in particular 2 *different* orderings were feasible).

the said pairing is then correlated with the update resultset.

in oracle sql:

```
update params p1
   set (p1.value, p1.desc) = (
           select emb.value
                , emb.desc 
             from (
                    select p2.value
                         , p2.desc
                         , p2.id_p
                         , rownum     rn 
                      from params p2
                     where p2.id_s = 10064
                  order by p2.value
                         , p2.desc
                  ) emb
             join (
                    select pm.value
                         , pm.desc
                         , pm.id_p
                         , rownum     rn 
                      from params pm
                     where pm.id_s = 11119
                  order by pm.value
                         , pm.desc
                  ) emb_master
                       ON (     emb_master.id_p = emb.id_p
                            AND emb_master.rn   = emb.rn   )
            where p1.id_s = 11119
              and emb_master.id_p     = p1.id_p
              and emb_master.value    = p1.value
              and emb_master.desc     = p1.desc
       )
 where p1.id_s = 11119
     ;
```

this scheme's viability hinges on the assumption that the result sets modulo each value of the tuple (`id_p`, `id_s`) be of the same cardibality. if thy don't, updates will be incomplete.

tested on ora 11g2 based on the excerpts given.

Comment: the problem is that my subquery returns more than one rows anyways and with or without your suggested addition i get the ora-01427, i thought the line 'and p2.id_p = p1.id_p' should help but it doesnt.

Comment: you shoould check again whether your subquery issued as a standalone query produces more than 1 row. i tested this version against ora 11g2 based on the table excerpt from your question and it works as expected.

Comment: you are right friend, i just edited my question corrected the possible values in the table. for example there can be more than one row for id_p with the same value

Comment: this is exactly what i need sir. Thanks a lot for your in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what to do when there is more than one row returned.  You can just select an arbitrary row using `rownum = 1`:

```
update params p1
   set (p1.value, p1.desc) = (
           select p2.value, p2.desc 
           from params p2
           where p2.id_s = 10064 and p2.id_p = p1.id_p and rownum = 1
       )
where p1.id_s = 11119;
```

Comment: i just edited my question corrected the possible values in the table. for example there can be more than one row for id_p with the same value. im just confused with the rownum, will this help in this case

Comment: @arminrock . . . The `rownum = 1` will choose one of the matching rows and use that for the update.  That will fix the error.  I don't know if that is what you want the query to do.